# How to "choose" binary variables which have a big impact on a regression?

Tags: multiple-regression, feature-selection, lasso, binary-data, ridge-regression

I am currently facing an issue with analyzing my data for a project.

I have a dataset of about  100.000 samples. I have approximate 50  columns which are all **binary** and my dependent variable is **time in hours**. Every row shows records of a process a product goes through, whether the product passed through the specified "stop".

My goal is not to make a prediction but rather an explanation/inference.

Assume that my dataset looks like this:

​

| stop1 | stop2 | stop3 | stop4 | ... | time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | ... | 23.35 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | ... | 8.26 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | ... | 200.06 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | ... | 1.71 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | ... | 2.03 |

How can you "measure" the impact of these variables on the final time? I imagined that doing a simple Linear Regression would give me an insight into what the "impact" of the different binary variables are on the dependent one?

How can you decide which variables to use for your regression and which ones to leave aside because they're not "relevant" to the final dependent variable?

(Again, this is for understanding if a specific stop takes way more time than others do for example, and if so I should look into it more, not for predictions.)

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! I see that you tagged this with [tag:lasso] and [tag:ridge-regression]. I won't say that those are wrong approaches, but they make it look like you have some thoughts on how to approach the problem. It would be helpful if you explained why.

Comment: Why choose? You have about a 2000/1 observation/predictor ratio, which should let you build a comprehensive model and directly evaluate all 50 predictors. Even if you included all 1225 two-way interactions among 50 predictors, you have so many cases that you probably wouldn't be in danger of overfitting.

Answer (score 0):

Let $time_{i}$ as $y_{i}$ and the $\{\mathbf{x}_i\}_{i=1}^{N}$ as your predictors (stops) where $\mathbf{x}_i$  is equal to the row $i$ of your dataset taking the last columns out and $i$ is the row index.

Take a deterministic regression problem where you want to fit:

$y=f(x;\mathbf{\Theta})$, $\mathbf{\Theta}$ as an arbitrary dimensional parameter.

Take

$\mathbf{\hat\Theta}=argmin_{\mathbf{\Theta}}\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{N}L(y_i,f(\mathbf{x}_i;\mathbf{\Theta}))$

Where $L$ is any loss function that the minimum exists.

A good idead is to choose the $k$ variables which increases  $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{N}L(y_i,f(\mathbf{x}_i;\mathbf{\Theta}))$ the most if we are not using then for example fit the model taking $stop_1$ out and fit the model taking $\mathbf{z}=(stop_2,...,stop_4)$, and check the value of:

$Q(stop_1)=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{N}L(y_i,f(\mathbf{z}_i;\mathbf{\Theta}))-\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{N}L(y_i,f(\mathbf{x}_i;\mathbf{\Theta}))$

Now take $\mathbf{s}=(stop_1,...,stop_3)$ and evaluate

$Q(stop_2)=\displaystyle\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{N}L(y_i,f(\mathbf{s}_i;\mathbf{\Theta}))-\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{N}L(y_i,f(\mathbf{x}_i;\mathbf{\Theta}))$

if $Q(stop_1)\geq Q(stop_2)$ so the variable $stop_1$ is more important than $stop_2$ since taking it out has increased the average loss the most.

So the $k$ most important variables are:

$\mathbf{MT}(k)=max^{(k)}\{Q(stop_1),...,Q(stop_4)\}$, where this evaluates which the $k$ large values are.

Comment: if the loss is mean-square error, how does this differ from the one-step fitting of an OLS model to the data including all the binary predictors, and then keeping the $k$ with the largest-magnitude coefficients?

Comment: The original question can be answered by computing confidence intervals on variable importance measures.  See [this](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/validate) for some examples.